# SQL - How to SELECT declared variables into #temp table

Tags: sql-server-2000

I want to do

> SELECT @var1, @var2 
>   
> INTO #myTempTable

I keep getting error

```
There is already an object named '#myTempTable' in the database.
```

My code goes

```
CREATE TABLE #myTempTable
(
   [value1] varchar(10),
   [value2] varchar(20)
)

declare @var1 varchar(10), @var2 varchar(20)

SELECT @var1 = [value1], @var2 = [value2]
FROM somePermTable
where Condition = true

SELECT @var1, @var2 INTO #myTempTable

drop table #myTempTable
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You must of added drop table @myTempTable at a later point, so SQL Server still sees this table.  Open a new query window and do a `drop table #myTempTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INSERT INTO #TempTables SELECT @var1, @var2`
`Select ... into` creates a new table (which is already created in your case). `Insert ... select` inserts data into existing table.

**Update**
More explanation.
SQL Server doesn't allow creating 2 tables with the same name. In your case you have local temporary table which is created twice (1st time `CREATE TABLE`, 2nd `SELECT ... INTO..`), so you get an error.
Depends on what you want you can
1. Drop table and create it again
2. Remove all data (if any) from it and populate it with `INSERT INTO... SELECT`

Comment: +1 This gets rid of the error.  Any idea what is causing that error?  I tried multiple table names (some odd that I KNOW are not in the DB, but I always got this stinky error).

Comment: But this doesn't explain why the error happened.  The error occurrs because the temp table #myTempTable existed, so you tried re-creating it again.  The only reason the error went away was becase you are INSERTING into an existing table rather then creating a new one.  That should be mentioned.  Sorry but this answer is not the correct answer, it merely got rid of the error because you changed how you inserted the data.

Comment: @JonH : I'm not sure I follow. I mentioned that `Select ... into` creates a new table, and that the table already exists at that point.

Comment: @a1ex07 - your initial post had a one liner mainly, to `INSERT INTO @myTempTable...` you made no mention of why the error occurred.  You simply maneuvered around the problem, so I didn't feel that was a good answer to the question.  Then you added the `which is already created...` portion, it helped the answer but it still seemed like a sloppy solution.

Comment: @JonH: Ok, that makes sense; at that time I was still editing my answer... But the main problem in my opinion is that it didn't use the proper statement to populate existing table with data

Answer (score 0):

You must have added drop table @myTempTable at a later point, so SQL Server still sees this table. Open a new query window and do a

`drop table #myTempTable`

Then you can execute your original command:

```
CREATE TABLE #myTempTable
(
   [value1] varchar(10),
   [value2] varchar(20)
)

declare @var1 varchar(10), @var2 varchar(20)

SELECT @var1 = [value1], @var2 = [value2]
FROM somePermTable
where Condition = true

SELECT @var1, @var2 INTO #myTempTable

drop table #myTempTable
```

Looks like you have a temp table already, simply drop it first

`DROP TABLE #myTempTable`

Answer (score -1):

```
declare @R(empno number,ename varchar(30),sal number);

insert into @R(select empno,ename,sal from emp where deptno=20);
```

How to convert the above SQl server code to Oracle PL SQL.
Anyone can suggest what concept we have to use for this.